# Composer Versioning for Thrift Client Libraries

Tags: php, composer-php, versioning, thrift

I have a service created with apache thrift and a `*.thrift` file that can be used to generate client libraries.

The service and the `*.thrift` file has it's own versions (e.g. `2.3.0`).

Now I would like to pre-generate the client for PHP to make it loadable with composer but thrift itself has it's own versions generating different files (e.g. `0.9.1`).

My idea was to pre-generate the service with different thrift versions and tag that like the following:

```
<CLIENT-MAJOR>.<CLIENT-MINOR>.<CLIENT-PATCH>.<THRIFT-MAJOR>.<THRIFT-MINOR>.<THRIFT-PATCH>
```

but composer don't like that version:

```
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                            
Could not parse version constraint 2.3.0.0.9.1: Invalid version string "2.3.0.0.9.1"
```

What can I do? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the generated code differs between versions, the service itself is backwards compatible - and that's what counts. So there is no need for including the Thrift version. Otherwise you may also consider including your PHP version number.

Comment: The generated code isn't compatible in all cases! For example between thrift 0.8 and 0.9 PHP namespaces were added and that's a big API change. Btw. the generated code requires the PHP thrift library in the same version! see https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/0.8.0/lib/php & https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/0.9.1/lib/php

Comment: The service's external behaviour is backwards compatible, not necessarily the PHP-related stuff. And again, that's what counts. Nobody is going to deal with your code, but with the exposed service.

Comment: I like to tag the generated PHP Client Library. The service itself has it's version and is fine. If you like to use the service with PHP you need the generated client library and there it's a big difference if you generate it with different versions - PHP client API is different, dependencies are different and btw. incompatible with each other (you can't use the PHP thrift lib of 0.9 and 0.8 the same time). What you mean is the service / thirft client itself but this is not usable without additional work/knowledge.